# How to combine two booleans in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm using robot framework to test if a webpage opens correctly. The webpage has two possible outcomes if everything works as planned:

```
${element_1_visible} =   Run Keyword And Return Status       Element should be visible      element_1
${element_2_visible} =   Run Keyword And Return Status       Element should be visible      element_2
```

These variables are always `True` and `False`, so a simple `or` operation should be enough. How do I combine these two booleans to test if my page works? So far have tried:

```
Should be True  ${element_1_visible}     or      ${element_2_visible}
Should be True  ${element_1_visible} == True     or      ${element_2_visible} == True
```

also:

```
${result} =  ${element_1_visible}     or      ${element_2_visible}
Should be True  ${result}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that needs to be evaluated should be a single argument. This means prevent multiple spaces, as 2+ consequtive spaces  is the divider between arguments.

Updated your example, this now works.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${element_1_visible}     Set Variable     ${True}
    ${element_2_visible}     Set Variable     ${False}

    Should be True      ${element_1_visible} or ${element_2_visible}
    Should be True      ${element_1_visible}==True or ${element_2_visible}==True

    ${element_1_visible}     Set Variable     ${False}
    ${element_2_visible}     Set Variable     ${False}

    Should not be True      ${element_1_visible} or ${element_2_visible}
    Should not be True      ${element_1_visible}==True or ${element_2_visible}==True
```